# Decoding charset of JSON response

Tags: json, rest, encoding

I'm using Dev HTTP Client Chrome extension to verify restful URL so i can build C# application that can consume it. I have a trouble with encoding meaning when response is shown inside plugin/browser encoding is not proper, but when i download it with that same plugin and open file with Notepad++ encoding is fine. I'm having same problem with my C# application when reading JSON response from that web service. I also used restclient-ui-3.1 to check data but it behaves same as Chrome plugin, meaning it displays wrong characters in its response body tab.

Obviously web service is sending properly encoded data but i can't manage to read it accordingly on client side. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dev HTTP Client uses Content-Encoding and Content-Type HTTP headers to determine how is response body encoded (e.g. Content-Encoding: gzip) and what representation contains (e.g. Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8).

It seems that your webservice is not sending proper HTTP headers. Check them.